# Адаптация изображения

Tags: html

Изображение на 100% монитора, однако в мобильных устройствах виден только левый кусок этого изображения. Не пойму, почему не адаптируется и выходит за рамки дисплея. Что не так?

```
.cont {
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: auto;
}


<div class='cont'>
<img src='https://.....png'/>                  
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.cont{
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
.cont img {
  width: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class='cont'>
<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAkGBxIQEhUSEhIWFRUVFxUWFxcVFxUYGBcVGBcXFhUXFxcYHSggGholHRcWIjEiJSkrLi4uFx8zODMtNygtLisBCgoKDg0OGxAQGy0mICUtLS8tLS8vLS0tLy0tLS0tLS0tLS8tLS0tLS0tLS0vLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLf/AABEIALcBEwMBIgACEQEDEQH/xAAbAAABBQEBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAAECAwUGB//EAD0QAAEDAgQDBgQFAgUEAwAAAAEAAhEDIQQSMUEFUWETInGBkaEGFDJCUrHB0fBi4RUjgpLxY3Ki4gczU//EABoBAAMBAQEBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAgMEBQb/xAA1EQACAgECBAMFBwMFAAAAAAAAAQIRAxIhBDFBURNhkQUUcdHwFTJSgaHB4QYisRZiY3Ki/9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwDhxlHVNm6BOGpwxfYaTwtRAyU2VXBicMRRNlORPkV4YnDEgsoyJwxEBim1qlhYMKXRTFA8kWwK5jgpbZSSAPlyl8uVpgp4CVselGX8ueSXYHktQMCIpUWpah6EYgwzuSmME47Lo6eHatLB8Dq1Rmp03OHMC3lzUvJXMtYrOM+QfyTHBOGy7vC8DqvcGimRJIl4LWiNZMJcV4DXoSTSzAbsMiOfMKfGV1Y/B2s4H5Z3JQdSK6TE4ZwaHmm4NdcOgwfArPqZVop2ZuNGSaaYsRj2hVFq0IBsibKiC1NlToLKMqbKr8qbKigspypZVblTZUDsqypoV0KMJhZXCUKyEoQMgFJPCfKgQySfKnTAmGKQYrgxSDFRmUhikGK8MUgxDFZQGJwxECmnDFIWUCmum+HfhF2IINWabTEWu79gh+D4bK4PI8J/Neh8Nx1NrBcAxuuPiMziqideDCpbyLsL8JYWkA1tMGYnNe45zqiR8OYcOnsaZgyO6InSQEM3iwnWUdRx0ixErzJPL1Z3pQ7AfG/hvC12huRtMi8sDWk89l55ivhnEOq1GUKFRzWGJO/XMYBnkF6nQw4JzPdJ1tz6o5uLItIPsU4cTPHst/iRPDGfPY8Pq8IxFNpe+i5rRu4RfpOuiDzkL3WviHHSL7GCFyfGeEUA7tDTAcTJIJBzc7Gy68XF6vvI558NX3WclgOA4hxaan+Ux1y513R0aLyvQ+A1wym2lT0baTYu6kcyucOJA1cT4mUVw3iAbIbqVGa8i3NMaUDtqdXNylKoxuhjrZc/h+IEGXEBaFPiTXakLheJpnUpovcMgyhoy7ANsPJefVfg8V61VzgacuJaG5YjcxtK7erxFsGajW9Jv6LNGJqOvTaS3mbHyBuujC5wujHIoy5nlXGOGOw1U03XjQjcbIDKvQOJ/CVXE1DUzBk6h0k9IA2WFX+EMU0E5A4Ax3TPsvThmi1u9zz54pJ7LY5stTZUVVoFphwII2Igpm4dxBIa4gakAkDxIW1mQLlTZVeWpsqYFBamLVeWqJamAqGEc8Ewco1OwVL2QeaMw+JfTBDTE69Qq6r81yLpb2XtQJlThqtyqTRCYinInyItlS8wJ8FY+sXGSBPglbKpAGRJaYxruQ9Aki5dh1HuVhimKaIDd0Qx51gW6BU5MySQEKSup4UkSBK0DiS8iQLdFZiWgCZusnN8itC5gNDCBxgyFficA1kFrp8VXCldD1XzEnGuQ5rut0UqWKcNSoBqmKKTUeoKUuhp4PEzcLoMBirLlaByrSw+JhceWHY7MeTudV25OhTtxgEh0yszBYsbrQp5DfdcrVczoTsyMVxxwJDXQRsR+6BfxKo+O0DoO61+I4dusA9YHogH4nLZbx01sjGWq92A1w2YB9bFQpiCiasOMpm0x4qq2JsvpDndbfDsOHELlTjnsdBaLbLUwvxIGfaZSninWw45oXuE8bwlWjVFSk1rzzIAc2NpB7w1RnDviAubFQZXDUXWVX+Jc/2ws449j5zEg9EvCk41JB4sU7izvKWIziwB81OkIJEfquGw/FmsAyFw8Tr5LUwHGQblx9VlLA0axypm7ivh2lXntKIeDF5yuEciPyR/COGMwoLGAhpNwTI5b9I9FlUeLwZa4HoSAicRxnumZB6XHqsJxytab2NE4c+pnfG/weMUBVoBjKg+qQRnEWEi3svKn4QtcWusWmDIK9aPxKGN711w3xBxAVXOLWgZjeAJPKTuu3hZ5IrTLl0ObPCEnqRy72DZQIRNSmVXkXbqkzmaiimEsquypsq0VmexTlSyq6EsqYFOVShWZUsqYWQhMrcqSAs0QxTDFYGqYYpskrDVMNUwxTaxS2BUGKQpq9jUUKgGgUuTRSinzM8MU2tRpDTtCsFNhsbdQpc/IejzAQnuiBQ6qxlMDW6VoKZRSqkbrRw1V7x3UOGtOjfdaeCyM7wOXmFjkarka4rvmQfSrHu/UeST+DVDrHPXTxR2J4u2RAnwVFbigGglYrX0Ru3j6sznYKqDZsxvKtdg3Bme87jRI8RdyVb8WXCCVrU2ZaoLkzMqkuMlV5EY9t1A010JnMwQsUSxFliiaaqxAhYmEjRFGmoFidgDZnDQlJ2IqaZ3R4lXFircxGwWwZ5cdz6qlzUY5irLFQWCFqgWIssUCxMAUtTZUSWJixMAfKllV2VLKgCnKnDVblT5UwKsqStypIA0w1TDVNrVMNWLZVEA1SDVMNUw1KwogGqYaphqkGqbHRDKpBqmGqYapsKKwE4arA1PlSsCsNUg1TDUxIGpA8wk5JcxpES1NlVuVPlTsVFOVLKrsqWVFhRSWpsqvypsiLCgctTFiIypi1OwoGLFAsRRaoFqaYqBSxQNNFliiWKrFQG6mqzTRpYoGmqsVARpqBpo001E007CgE01EsRppqJpqrACLE2RGGmommnYAuRLIiOzSyIsAfKkiMiSLA0Q1SDVMNUw1YWaEA1TDVMNUg1TYUQDVMNUw1TDVNjorDVMNUw1SypWOiuEJieJUqYJLxPKbk9EPxuZjPltIADrnmSLdPMLm3FrDmcS4uBuIiJtPnGhXz3He18mLI8eNL4t2/Tp+Z048CkrZo1OMOfMEmdMunTS58Fn1qZP1GMslx1v0UquLLqZfT/zCxpsMstbBLwLyTH5eCyWcQpluY1AXwCACYDLaQQLWtrfzXhShmzPVK35v9vr8jrSS5GxwjihaXBlTNsM8taPGTH6LqOHYsPBlzZbrExGxuF5nUx/1dmZs6TBFjq0u1M329EXheLuIaQ2A6Zh2gFtPRd3D8Xl4dLTut9n9fsRPCpnp4EiQllXFYD4kqMaSXZ5MZXk5vEDlH5Tour4RxAV2ySA78O41uRqJsvd4b2jDM1Bpp/ock8LjuFZU2REIDjfEBhqL6piQIbO7jZv7+AK73OlbM1G3SK28QolxZ2jczSWkExcai+vkiuzXk+De7MJJc6qXODY1a2czyTpJkeI6rUw+NqU/oe5sbAkX5Fuk+K48fHauaOyfBVyZ6H2XVRdTXJUPimq368rx17p9Rb2QnDeO9lUrVC1zjUJLQXaDMSBJvA8Ft73C0Z+6Sp/VnaliiWLkT8V1s4JDI1LACO7pOa5ka25Ltezm40WuLiIZL09DHJgnjrV1BSxRLEWaaYUiVvqMtIGWKJpo00Cm7Ap6w0gJppuzRxoFMaBT1i0gBpKJpI80U3Yp6w0mf2Sbslodh0UhhjyT1hpM3sklqfJlJLxEPQyAanMASTAGpOitDU7qQcCCAQbEG4I6hZN9ikjlOMfEwByUXCbCYBOsGJU+HfEbh/9ozAWJaBmB6i1ly3EsEG1Kga3Nkc5ubVsyIaLbSJ68lLAkCxaTdxuSA0ySIiw9NhovnMnE5lPVqdr0PRWKGmqPUKDg9ocNCJV2VU8LdmpU3Wu0aaaLl/jLiLw40vsGWQPuJg97w9F6+XifDxKfOzkji1So7ANTkACSYAuT0XH/AeOr1HGmQDTa2Z32AiOdvddhjapp03OiQB0jzk6JR4lSxPJyq/0CWPTKjmuK8QNR4pnut1G5JNh7ErMx2GpUaYByucC10gZs7QZcy5gAi0kW+rUJcQa0ud2js+l2usD3SRNxqUBxPFtY1vZsa1omD9Wh1gCXdPAL49cTmefXzd9a+vT8jsUFVEKmCa+ahDG5jmiGiGW7ojQBp25jcrG4QHZKrmhrQXwe5mN2yRfYTMdDZbNHHOcHuP/AHAxIjYkCSQLW6IGo5tQ/wCbsXZajRlBAEmCRrDgdz3k4SnclLr1RfQiwAtkNJptMEtbdxsdd3d7rsnweAc+pDGguInLAc+InQbyfZNhcO2kYsCWkFzg5wIMHXQXGgIKt/xCqCK7SCyCAWk20EZo0k/psrck5bXXX+A3KLUnkkuH0OG4kyTMG0gWbH5L1zhbXvptc9sEgG0XkAzaw8F55gHU8W6m15cLzIaXOki0QJcL7z5r0rgnDKlCkKbn5spdBJJJaSS2Z3gr2PZtr+5dt/j5mGVWW/Lrz347xoq4hmFa4BrD3iT9xEk/6W+5K77jWKGGoPrOP0CwJ1cbNHmSFwXwTw/t3VMS/vOOe+vPO6dCc3LkuvjMv9uhdf8ABpwuLfU+hXW+IcBhrUwKr2tDe40EwNAXbamyfifCX1GDENaA9wDiwbgiR/qg6ojH8GpwxwYO7VBsOTRcxtJPmu2xBodkwB4c7KyQyXkSNw0E+q4fu7nVzPHXvmFq/D3CfmagDjlZNyZv5q7jXw0X99tKrMu7QOsHNl3eh7gc0Rt6b9zjeFChRZSpsbTqFvfJLe8LaOFzGnmUTy7bDjDfczPjT4VY2kythi1zqYvBBkeWx/QLlOG8QxTgKNB7y2HOa1oGYACXNkiRHiI8l1nDsK9j8pEMd9UEQP6o2Oo8xyXFcYb8rjajWltQU6jKjXBoLZGWo0kDW9iByKiE5QlcWaOMZxpnefAOIOOpFhP+ZT+rMTJbsTN5Gh8ua6itwdzATIMfhn9l5HwL4hfhMQ7E0wym55dmbfIWudmLQHXAmNL2XrnBfi+ljWDs4a8DvU3EEjmQfub1HsvSx58lJNnDPDC20C9kl8ueS0QpLp8RmHhozDh+YTNojYLWzBRkDQBLxGPw0ZnypO3sps4adyin1HTqIUDXPinrkLREZvDm7lXswlMKtpLtASmL4Sbb6lJJdAjsW8kkKMSP5KdKmO0YxqUhq9vqE3ztEfdPgD+yxW5Ju333SBYfw+pP6r5Kf9S8Q/uwS9X+6OTUjUpYzDsJLWkEmTlYbmwnxsELwzE06dEU305PfzZW905nOO/QoVhb+L0Cua10WDj4An9VzT9v8X3S/IakaVPi1MABtN3IABZPF8Lh8TmJouDzHfDouBAkbiwV7cNUOxHiAPzVowDzqY8S391z5PbvFSVSmvRfIpSkuRVwqnh8I5zqVJzczQ0jPMhpJB0ubrRrcTpVGFrqZLTYiY/YoQ4H/qN9R+6d2C/rCle3eJUdOpV/1XyHcmzK4hwqjUqTTYGNiSImakiCb2ty5LcDMIYzYeTDZGQFstGUGCdQEL2B/EPRRfQ/qHoFOP2vnhLUtO/kVqmYfHOF0KIa4OqdiXBtUOaJYHGO1B3aJOYGTcGbFYuE7OjiMRTqDLToCo+o+GyGvyZWU7AtqPytA6PO4k9biMK2oxzHO7r2lptsRBXm3BsBVfj/AJeq6zC3tP62UI7Mkbz3PIr0OD415NU3Scd9r3W3n8fzaNscm07PQuE/CQy06tZ/fLmvdSvkpyJLSbF14nmSdRZEn4cY6pXfVyhgY5zTRysBBa4OZk8IJ/Mza9tYjSofRO/FOggvkHYgR6Lmh7XapPFGl2bXzI8RnA8IFajV7SlmEOyh7dCDzd9MXE+I5he08GFR1BjqhlzgCZAEebSQRvPIrjKNYMBYwCCZIDWxJiSbX0C0MNj634oGwED8ltg9srDNycXXa/2orxE+h0nEuGMxDOzrMa9kgwZ1GhsuY4nwGiyhVo0y6mB9DWOc3LPfdBmSCTuTqiTxaqLB0n9f5/NJrxD3VfqNzaRI1gHQrrye3+HmlcWn8F8zTHkUXvZ5nxP4TZTdle8vM3cCDOYMMSeQK9wwjKbKFJoEgU2AA3+1o/RcBT+HKLWdm0Oa2S6zjMkAameQ9Fs/P1GgNmwED8rqftjhpd/T+TRZormb+PLW0ap1GR506f39/GAv/kbC1KjaDmUy5rWvLyBIaO4ZPkD6LKxXE6jmlhA7wLSRMwdd4R2K+JatSm6mWUwHNcw2dMEQYJdEo+1cHn6FLiIWcpwhhdVphrXEZxmDQfp7Rs5o2iVP414EauPruymD2EG8GWFpHlkb4SFocIxRwj3Oa3NmBaQ69i4O2i8gLWr/ABI6q0tNNm2hM28VX2nw/O36D94gcPxD4dFOsKApnvdmA9ryPrAInNJtm9l6UzBYVmR7cLRFZjY7VtNjXg5SxxDgJNi4ea5nF1O0rNqkQW9nYEQcgEajeFoVOMkknsxck6la8N7W4VN638NmTnzQaWh/E3qTw60geqvawD6nW6Llxxg/hA81a3jXT3K7X7b4P8b9H8jmUkbtQnYEjmqJLv8AlZH+NEaCf9SqPGHDSmPUo+3OD/E/RibRr9pvOiubXaRcGYXOnjD/AMDVU/jFU/aFL9vcL/u9F8wujqMK57TmbcKT3te6XC51N9fBcmOL14gGAqXYqs7Vx9T+655/1Diu4wf6L5hq2o7AVI/gSXEljklj/qP/AI//AF/AtRLM2dG+eZxUxUYNhPRoQLAwbl3gCn7Tk1w8RC+b0HOaDMUdZI8wnbiAfvJ8FnmfwT43VgcTsPIGVLxodhvaN3cfAuT9swf8oIMMXDv54KPZ9PdvuEtC7hYb84Nv1UKmIcdCPGP3VIZG/uFY1k7+sfulpig3Kqj3jWooh5O/mRCIgfyEzKc6KrQyoVXA3IjoCuXrcKxDcW/F030sz5GVwdAbDRz17ouuu+VJOk+YUmYE8gfP+y0xcR4VtVuqfwKUpLZHLVMdxIaUqLvAkD3el85xLfCUz4VP/Zdb8nuRprqkym0/TcjZsn309VfvcPwR/X9mG/VHN4fieNBvgB1iq39UdS+IHkCcJWGZxaINIyRM5ZItY30stF9EPlp03awy49HO0b4T5q2lgTmzuF4hoEQ1v4W89BJ3gcgs55cT3cF6v5jLcDDhmcHN2hwEtHKxM9TuiHCmPuiOfM/wIN4J+10C/ioF7TMscJ8eS5XG3YWaJw7Zs8KNTC7S31Wc6oDBBPIqvPEd420tsdvBCxy7hYW/CuGlx4hU1KJ6qr5jr/ZV1Hg7z4ytVGXUCw4WpsCQodm4asKH7Qg/UbaXuPPceKuOJP3O8/5f0laaZAhzm/CVIB3JUuqT9wnx/TQqt4qfa+P54/qjSMM7w+33Vb6xGrfZDZq4+53kUhWrfiJ8j+yej4Dsv7czoCpdseX5ITtanP2KXfPI/wA6p6AsLNZ3L2Tisf4CgTTcbR+iQwbydSPP+6NEerCw/t/5dOKnX3KA+QqcyoHBv0JRoh3CzRNXqPVJZ/yrvxeySNEe4G+cMwH6m/zyVnYsG49yuebiMxkPcJGnLTl4z5J8zwQGua4O2JMzGoix0G+wWbwS6sztdjo2iju+88o01j3UoofiPoT5LmfmiIk2BAMEkdTdRpYgE3Pd85sDtzn9UvdX3YWjqmNw+3M6ga+ikDh9bedly5xMybQTbXydrrcD0TjFAmM2/U3mDqdNPRT7q+7Hq8jpxUw0CD6af2Sa6gdz/wCPsSud7cxOa3Qk69dVBtQ/imYBvP5jyU+7ebHq8jpnGiJ18yANYuVHNSOkExzPO+gK581wTcAi5i3WfRSbVvEQCZEbwREdEe7+bDUbZDYmJFtA4nW2pCelQF7EdZYLdIBKwu3JHoZEeWptZQbWJ1Bkj1vCfgPuGpG/VwLSIkc+8HPv0l0DRNU4W131Pc4fhJhlv6W6+axjVIjUi1wb7eygzFcnEEWIJNuv5IWHJ0kPUjfbgyBDYjQACB5BIUXevM3XPOxLr99w5EEeUdE1PHObMVH3mziDeemifu8+4rR0NWjGrupuB6eyqrUSAIeJG0zeFjHiVS5c4xGlri0qtmPcNQdRe3K10Lh5oLRuCgRoQfIqipgSZIHl/As5nF3bXBm3566pHivrrHLaeqpYciHaC3YQzEwdx/aFS/CP5e4/mygOKFwuJ5G8eo09tFAcWF45wJm/n6eqtQyLoGw5wz4+n9f5uq+wd+GPb2Vg4uIhzb7RFynPGWDnfaNN/MqksnYewMaBH2x5fz81AUiJt6fqUaOLMmDa3I+g/myc8VZbfUSI29CneT8IAWU8vQT5zNkpPX+egWj/AInT3OvMnfySbxKk61iLdIOg2G38sjVP8IGe1507w9f0BUi/x9v1K0PnqOhgeIOsAx7KPztCYm9jf0nkAlqf4WAK0nrf+k6+QI2UGu/qjxI08wj2VKB5XtEgk36pziKX794edwdlOryYAYkxf8j7hIh19SNNP2Rna0hECTaR3XT1/XyT069KxsdNA0zPgD/OSNT7ADBj/wAKSu7ekP7hk+6dK32AzM1Owe0kWI2+7f8A8vQq3K11o6C5MkQBc7XTl4cYGjc3LLljVtrG0Rb6uqBaIkNqDvh2suFgASBoRABtuR4LdKzO6KjmBAy/VoZNmkx7yB5pntqt+hhLmwTOmWBDrDW5t062OFXLbSLmbmIOk7XjofBaBrNEMnvW+oTAA+q2txtpKqWVroCozm4dzmDPIkyGxyH1HpI9lBuEe2JAmBEkTmuSJiwFzojcTTjO5rjka2IJDbxJ+nY7HS8WQ76pohoIklrnASXD7cxI1mM3ofASpN8inEprZ2GXaSAOpIMH3HuohjmAEuAEjaYE305ayjK1UuINm2zhvetsQTFvuHWycuc8EBoeO/DnbjKbZedhAJMx1Ket1uiaAqjoFrODiCeogwBrGg9eaTXZzId071zrtGszp4dSpVsIe8Q5sGwaDDrE5ifGNbRCi/BA9nleO79U6d7KJjneQNLlWnEdE5cBmBgbRMiT3bHUjXzTOqkyCTpI1Gsnfr+SZ2EJMiBe8RYbAxyANufiobHJqIBGsAzqI0gt/wBpRSCi5pvMwdRFwdIPsBChVqGReTptqbgCd9lSbATeQIIkWgdN8xVQoOLiTvNgdxqDPLu/7lSihUF53BhLgIbreRBkz+ZsodtzgTNhe5JB181VXJEi5gC4NokCwi8ZlViGEG0mSG+4gk6XjnsVUYIdBd5uI1sDpvF9Bp6dEPUrkyLgNi41PLb/AIQ/Z3jM4zDrwASSbW9/FXOkEmD9LhE3I3EAxy67qtKQE3A92TMjQeEEW6nnum1IuNtLmNojyTOc4ukCRaRO8iBABn12UKAdAD2galtvqJFo5DTyTrYCwTli4E7X52HInu+qhVLQCLiLam5uRI8o8leL2IjukxcC2gv4H0UnUQ4CTaNIjyHl3t4vulaQzPdXN/qkdLdDcqYxE6EamCWmTHKdBr6FElsAg5r73tG58dfLcpskwQARbKDzk+YABPe8eqq12AoOKJJHdkwOg1nT/u/RN8y4GcgNr33kg+WttbeSiGts0U5Drkx9oaDuOYHkVcKrRAc3LBANiTvv4/lqqaS6ARqVheQRrIAMgCdhcck7qzBa4uNNZNv38yr3CmAZMXAjKCSQe95bT08xKvlYO+S6wBEWPd0nW0+XJRa7CtFdGCD3wbSDaxjfadvNUOo1R9NUEEnUdOniEXWp02tGaZMOtYS0373pYc/BXtpgwGg2BJLzsAJ36nwU6qCwI0nkXc1jtLSfGQdDNlLsXNEEhxgmYtybF4v+6IkQ4kAwMxgzcgnWJs2TA5+CnnbAcbC5aL950HQzAdAnz8UnJ9gsBc6o3MMobBaAe9YExcjyjf8ANO7FnKCHa+4B/Tn1RlWpTDgTYiDa0nNcQB/LJPpNbmaBIkjvcrBpIcJBJI63CepdUAPQx7S0FpcBeIk7+ASRzeD0N2weQywOl7pJN4+zCkUUMKatyJg1GAOI2OabDc2M6hg02jU4eWOZDuzLrjN3yIbewERJa7rokksPEl4mnpuXKKQecIamb7cpBtfujuvMze+Yq0spCs4FxDm3ETGYRmdHSAAOiSSyi3Jtdl8iGhOotaAJBzEEAgw7uy3NqZgc47u6rDCXBpIsyBdxsC7KbjWBz+1JJJN0Ut0PRbnJIEgNmdO61zg0jWNT/stE3Dq95zXtObM3LkP4g479HOdpyCSS0i/7peXyYMueSXFriQ4gxp9hOcT1BJ80H8w2nmsQWECwGWC5pB5z3rpJLXEtTSfl/mhMk3ETAY7K5xkGCBlgNAIbtPn3irGvHdkbGSLSB9Ugazf1SSTlFJ19dQJMAzS4H7m62IPMA852VGIwoMHNGYtNpk3AM+NyR0TJKYt2MrxADagpg2yOLstrjlP8spYbM4ujvXM5jBEDLpobhqSS0ltC/IGgYViHNmHEd3kMzWgTzOnsru1aIBmZGgFyCDtvDm780klq4q0Imar2gknUvk8gMx0529VVUxcNDQ2e7AMwbEmPAABJJTFJqwZcDAANpJneDmMn2KnVqZZ5yGiNi45Wnno6dUklK3f13EG0oeA3Z14Nxs0dRYbdNFVXo5bg2yuc2eUmW227p/28ykksY/eCO5QymHOLR9RMS6SAG2EDkA1o8ZMJV5dNXKAA7LMD8BJAFyAHHXw5JJLRc/QO5TSw7XHKxpsftMEuPeuXWEBsSBqTsisMG1Yc4ZgAXBsuAHdLtd7Ty23SSVvqC5oVGkyoMxgXc0CLDugNgN/E7MTyyhKtw0XJeQ4B2Y3EjM3NYTrI9uSSSybalSYiWE4DUbLXPJMFzgN2Ad0ifukdLhLD0AA285SQQLCIg5fIzJk90DQJkln4spXY2qQOOHZXOe8glwfJIn6ZJmNonTn5K3s3tqObmbNMl2UguggtNTXm7LudOl0ktoSclbJJspj/APZwubZTzvo4fkkkkr0GTluf/9k='/>                  
</div>
```